# NoClassDefFoundError: org/eclipse/persistence/internal/oxm/mappings/Field

Tags: java, xml, xsd, jaxb

I am creating a Java Code which creates XML dynamically based on XML Schema. I am using Jaxb for this. Here is my Code:

```
public class Testing2 {
    private static void traverseProps(DynamicJAXBContext c, DynamicEntity e, DynamicType t, int level) throws DynamicException, InstantiationException, IllegalAccessException{
        if (t!=null) {
           // logger.info(indent(level) + "type [" + t.getName() + "] of class [" + t.getClassName() + "] has " + t.getNumberOfProperties() + " props");
            for (String pName:t.getPropertiesNames()){
                Class<?> clazz = t.getPropertyType(pName);
              //  logger.info(indent(level) + "prop [" + pName + "] in type: " + clazz);
                //logger.info("prop [" + pName + "] in entity: " + e.get(pName));

                if (clazz==null){
                    // need to create an instance of object
                    String updatedClassName = pName.substring(0, 1).toUpperCase() + pName.substring(1);
              //      logger.info(indent(level) + "Creating new type instance for " + pName + " using following class name: " + updatedClassName );
                    DynamicType child = c.getDynamicType("generated." + updatedClassName);
                    DynamicEntity childEntity = child.newDynamicEntity();
                    e.set(pName, childEntity);
                    traverseProps(c, childEntity, child, level+1);
                } else {
                    // just set empty value
                    e.set(pName, clazz.newInstance());
                }
            }
        } else {
          //  logger.warn("type is null");
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException, JAXBException, DynamicException, InstantiationException, IllegalAccessException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        String PATH_TO_XSD = "C:/.....XSD.xsd";

        String YOUR_ROOT_TYPE = "Doc";
        InputStream in = new FileInputStream(PATH_TO_XSD);
        DynamicJAXBContext jaxbContext = DynamicJAXBContextFactory.createContextFromXSD(in, null, Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader(), null);
        DynamicType rootType = jaxbContext.getDynamicType(YOUR_ROOT_TYPE);
        DynamicEntity root = rootType.newDynamicEntity();
        traverseProps(jaxbContext, root, rootType, 0);
    }

}
```

I am getting below error, although I have added the jars: jaxb-xjc-2.2.11.jar and jaxb-core-2.3.0.jar. Can anyone help me in Debugging the Problem:

```
 Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/eclipse/persistence/internal/oxm/mappings/Field
    at org.eclipse.persistence.jaxb.dynamic.DynamicJAXBContext$SchemaContextInput.createContextState(DynamicJAXBContext.java:284)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.jaxb.JAXBContext.<init>(JAXBContext.java:174)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.jaxb.dynamic.DynamicJAXBContext.<init>(DynamicJAXBContext.java:71)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.jaxb.dynamic.DynamicJAXBContextFactory.createContextFromXSD(DynamicJAXBContextFactory.java:279)
    at com.sap.Testing2.main(Testing2.java:48)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.eclipse.persistence.internal.oxm.mappings.Field
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:338)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    ... 5 more
```

Comment: which JAXB library you are using?  why not use official one?

Comment: I am using  jaxb-xjc-2.2.11.jar and jaxb-core-2.3.0.jar

Comment: Seems you are using eclipselink .  
 https://www.eclipse.org/eclipselink/api/2.3/org/eclipse/persistence/jaxb/dynamic/DynamicJAXBContext.html

If so , you need make sure all the eclipseLink dependency is complete. Check your pom dependency

Comment: I am not using Maven. I simply added the jars in Project build path.

Comment: then go to [here](https://www.eclipse.org/eclipselink/) get a complete version which is greater than 2.5.1. As `Field` is created in that version according to [here](https://www.eclipse.org/eclipselink/api/2.7/index.html)